# How to add character count for each dynamicall created text field with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, clone

This is the code that I am using for my text fields

```
$('#option').bind('keyup', function() {
    var maxchar = 140;
    var cnt = $(this).val().length;
    var remainingchar = maxchar - cnt;
    $('#charsLeft').html(remainingchar);
    if(remainingchar > 0){
        $('#charsLeft').css('color', 'green');
    }else{
        $('#charsLeft').css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

This works great but now I need to apply it to all text inputs that are cloned. Each cloned input field gets a number added to it.

For example:

```
option1
option2
option3 ...
```

I was playing around with this but didn't get far:

```
var list = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    list.push(i);
}
$(list).each( function(i, val){
    $('#option').limit('140', '#charsLeft');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Proper indentation would be a plus - EDIT: Thanks am not i am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete solution.

You can attach the existing event to newly cloned elements using .live().

```
$("input[name='option']").live('keyup', function() { });|
```

The working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f6zKy/

Final Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/spJV3/5/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, except my inputs have an incrementing number after each name. So there isn't a one generic name for all of the inputs. Please check this out. You will see where I need to add the max character. http://jsfiddle.net/spJV3/2/

Comment: Here is the full-fledged solution. 
http://jsfiddle.net/spJV3/5/

Have fun man... :-)

Answer (score 1):

to get ID that starts with "option"

```
$("[id^=option]")
```

see jquery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1) if all of those textboxes can be put inside a container, do so. `<div id='container'>`

2) use a class to identify all of those textbox. `<input type='text' class='optiontype' id='option' />`

3) use `.delegate()` or `.on()` (v1.7), this way you won't need to attach the event to each item

```
$('#container').on('keyup', 'input.optiontype', function(e) {
   ...
});
```

The main issue with your current setup is that .bind() only attaches to the existing objects